# c# Log4Net not writing file/console in docker

Tags: docker, log4net

I wrote a c# (.NET 6.0) console application which is a queue consumer and writes dequeued messages into log file. Everything is fine in local but as i dockerize the app i cant see neither a log file nor a console message even if the message is rightly acknoledge from the queue.

Here is log4net.config file with 2 appender

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="Elastic.CommonSchema.Log4net.EcsLayout, Elastic.CommonSchema.Log4net">
            
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\Users\t.domenici\source\repos\RabbitMqDemo\LogHandler\bin\Release\net6.0\Log\Log_" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+ExclusiveLock" />
        <datePattern value="dd_MM_yyyy'.log'"/>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
        <layout type="Elastic.CommonSchema.Log4net.EcsLayout, Elastic.CommonSchema.Log4net" />
    </appender>

</log4net>
```

and here is the docker command to create a bind mount, which is correctly created
`docker run -v C:/Users/********/source/repos/RabbitMqDemo/LogHandler/bin/Release/net6.0/Log:/app/LogHandler/Log -it --name LogHandler log-handler-image:1.0.0`
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Heyy, could you please include your Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml?

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 
RUN mkdir -p /app/LogHandler
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish /app/LogHandler
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/app/LogHandler/LogHandler.dll"]

Comment: Hm, it seem like the log4net.config is not getting copied into your docker, is that correct? Try adding `COPY {path to log4net.config} /app/LogHandler/` and see if the issue persist. Also, inside the log4net.config, change the file parameter to be `/app/LogHandler/Log`

Comment: Hi, the log4net.config is present into the image and i can rightly access it from docker desktop, because i set the copy to output directory property to  true  from visual studio. I tried to change the file parameter to /app/LogHandler/Log but the problem persists. The strange thing is that is not working neither the writing log file process nor the writing log on the console. If i use the Console.WriteLine command  in the c# code it works , showing messagese on the contairer log. The problem seems related to the log4net SDK.

Comment: Hm, seems strange. You could try reporting it as an issue to the maintainers, however I think there might be something small we've overlooked, since [there are examples of Log4Net working inside docker](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-using-log4net-and-gelf4net-to-elk-running). Could you please take a look at the linked article and see if there's something u've missed?

Comment: Hi and thanks to your replay. In the link you post the application uses log4net sdk but it sends message directly to the ELK stack vai UDP and  it is not logging on file. I'll look into it further anyway. I found this link which is related to my same problem but there is not a valid solution; the user is recommended to change the logging framework ( Nlog).

Comment: Is [enabling log4net internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeded to write log and print message using log4net sdk by adding  the WORKDIR /app/LogHandler command into the docker file. Now the file appears once the container is started and it is correctly update on every dequeued message. Even the console is working. Now it is time to create a volume to make the file persisting after conainer is switched off.
Here are the Dockerfile
[image]
and some results:
[image]

Thanks everybody for supporting me